# Error after Installation Symfony (app_dev.php)

Tags: symfony, fedora

When I'm going to: Localhost/path_of_project/web/Check%20app_dev.php I have this.. I don't understand why .. Because all of the project is on CHMOD 777 (Many problems on permissions..)

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException' in /var/www/whitesmoke/public_html/whitesmoke/vendor/sensio/framework-extra-bundle/EventListener/ControllerListener.php on line 89
( ! ) Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException: in /var/www/whitesmoke/public_html/whitesmoke/app/cache/prod/appProdUrlMatcher.php on line 39
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0005  238728  {main}( )   ../app.php:0
2   0.0200  1601096 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle( )  ../app.php:28
3   0.0437  3599400 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle( )    ../bootstrap.php.cache:2444
4   0.0437  3600624 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle( )  ../bootstrap.php.cache:3222
5   0.0437  3601576 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw( )   ../bootstrap.php.cache:3071
6   0.0445  3636880 Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch( )  ../bootstrap.php.cache:3098
7   0.0476  3932472 Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch( )    ../EventDispatcher.php:48
8   0.0501  4221216 call_user_func:{/var/www/whitesmoke/public_html/whitesmoke/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:160} ( )    ../EventDispatcher.php:160
9   0.0501  4221800 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener->onKernelRequest( )   ../EventDispatcher.php:160
10  0.0501  4222560 Symfony\Component\Routing\Router->matchRequest( )   ../RouterListener.php:137
11  0.0512  4321448 Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher->matchRequest( )   ../Router.php:256
12  0.0512  4321568 appProdUrlMatcher->match( ) ../UrlMatcher.php:112
( ! ) Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /Check%20app_dev.php" in /var/www/whitesmoke/public_html/whitesmoke/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php on line 159
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0005  238728  {main}( )   ../app.php:0
2   0.0200  1601096 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle( )  ../app.php:28
3   0.0437  3599400 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle( )    ../bootstrap.php.cache:2444
4   0.0437  3600624 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle( )  ../bootstrap.php.cache:3222
5   0.0437  3601576 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw( )   ../bootstrap.php.cache:3071
6   0.0445  3636880 Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch( )  ../bootstrap.php.cache:3098
7   0.0476  3932472 Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch( )    ../EventDispatcher.php:48
8   0.0501  4221216 call_user_func:{/var/www/whitesmoke/public_html/whitesmoke/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:160} ( )    ../EventDispatcher.php:160
9   0.0501  4221800 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener->onKernelRequest( )   ../EventDispatcher.php:160
( ! ) Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::getConfigurations() must be of the type array, integer given, called in /var/www/whitesmoke/public_html/whitesmoke/vendor/sensio/framework-extra-bundle/EventListener/ControllerListener.php on line 61 and defined in /var/www/whitesmoke/public_html/whitesmoke/vendor/sensio/framework-extra-bundle/EventListener/ControllerListener.php on line 89
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0005  238728  {main}( )   ../app.php:0
2   0.0200  1601096 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle( )  ../app.php:28
3   0.0437  3599400 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle( )    ../bootstrap.php.cache:2444
( ! ) Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::getConfigurations() must be of the type array, integer given, called in /var/www/whitesmoke/public_html/whitesmoke/vendor/sensio/framework-extra-bundle/EventListener/ControllerListener.php on line 61 and defined in /var/www/whitesmoke/public_html/whitesmoke/vendor/sensio/framework-extra-bundle/EventListener/ControllerListener.php on line 89
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0809  7921816 Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler->handleException( )    ../ErrorHandler.php:0
2   0.0839  8171088 Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler->handleException( )    ../ErrorHandler.php:511
```

Could you help me ? :s

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken you just asking wrong url.
There is no (and could not be) a path '/Check/app_dev.php'.

Instead of this try to request /app_dev.php url (without 'Check').

Look at Symfony project file system.
There is /app/check.php file and /web/config.php.

I assume you might want to access one of them.